# where is the error the output gives 08 in my code

Tags: c++

> Write a C++ function that takes 4 arguments, the first argument is a string regarded as the first operand, the second argument is another string regarded as the second operand, the third argument is a character regarded as operation that can be “+” or “-” or “*” and the last argument is the base of the operands. The function must return a string with the result of applying the operation on the two operands(the result must be in the same base). Example for inputs and outputs:
> The first operand is: 1243
> The second operand is: 441
> The operation is: -
> The base is: 5
> The result is: 302

my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int function( int oper1 , int oper2 , char sign , int base)
{
  int ansdec,rem,n;
  switch(sign)
  {
  case '+':
      ansdec=oper1+oper2;
      cout<<ansdec;
      break;
  case '-':
      ansdec=oper1-oper2;
      cout<<ansdec;
      break;
  case '*':
      ansdec=oper1*oper2;
      cout<<ansdec;
      break;
  }

  while(ansdec>0)
  {
      rem=ansdec%10;//rem=2
      ansdec=ansdec/10;//ansdec=77/5=15
      n=(rem*10)+rem;//n=20*10+3=203
  }

  int reverse=0,re;
  while(n>0)
  {
      re=n%10;//re=3
      reverse=(reverse*10)+re;//rev=3
      n=n/10;
  }
  return reverse;
}

int main()
{
    int oper1,oper2,base;
    char sign;
    cout<<"enter your problem"<<endl;
    cin>>oper1>>oper2>>sign>>base;
    cout<<"The first operand is:"<<oper1<<endl;
    cout<<"The second operand is:"<<oper2<<endl;
    cout<<"Theoperation is:"<<sign<<endl;
    cout<<"The base is:"<<base<<endl;
    int result=0,i=0,x,y;
    while(oper1>0)
    {
     x=oper1%10;
     y=x*pow(base,i);
     oper1=oper1/10;
     result=result+y;
     i++;
    }
    int r=0,c=0,z,v;
    while(oper2>0)
    {
     z=oper2%10;
     v=z*pow(base,c);
     oper2=oper2/10;
     r=r+v;
     c++;
    }
    cout<<function(oper1,oper2,sign,base)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Side note: none of the arguments are strings in the sense "string" is typically used around here. By the time they reach the function, they are `int`s and a `char`

Comment: Create sub-functions and test each sub-functions. Does the issue come from the transformation to base 10, from base 10, do you select correct operation?

Comment: @user4581301 I tried to solve it as a sting function but i didn't know how. so, i needed to assign an int to the function to do the math. thanks for ur help.

Comment: @Jarod42 I will try to do it as sub-functions and will tell u the result. The thing is i am a beginner. And thanks for the help.